# I have defined my functions but still get an error that definitions can not be found

Tags: c, function

Confused as to why my function definitions are not being picked up here.

```
double formula(double far, double cel);

double getDegrees(double far);

void display(double far, double cel);

int main()
{
    double far = 0, cel = 0;

    far = getDegrees(far);
    cel = formula(far, cel);
    display(far, cel);

    return 0;
}

double getDegrees(far)
{
    printf("Enter degrees fahrenheit\n");
    scanf_s("%lf", &far);
    return far;
}

double formula(cel, far)
{
    cel = (5.0 / 9) * (far - 32);
    return cel;
}

void display(cel, far)
{

    printf("%lf\n", cel);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your function definitions seem to have omitted types for the arguments?

Comment: This is why you should enable warnings when compiling.

Comment: Also, while this is probably a simplified example, I still want to mention that you could simply place your `main()` function a the bottom of the file and therefore drop the need for the forward declarations.

Comment: Thanks! As you can see I am stumbling my way through this. I'm literally brand new and going largely off of internet learning.

Answer (score 1):

Your function declarations include type information for parameters, and you need to repeat this for the function definitions. For example:

```
double getDegrees(double far)
{
    printf("Enter degrees fahrenheit\n");
    scanf_s("%lf", &far);
    return far;
}
```

The compiler will not automatically match the type information up.

Comment: Thank you! It's always something so simple that I miss.

Comment: While you're here, I should tell you that passing an argument to this function is pointless. Declare a double locally in the function and then return it after reading into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you define functions over `int main()` in the code, so your program knows what functions will you use, you can declare them both ways:

```
double formula(double far, double cel); // (1) type + variable name
double formula(double, double);         // (2) only type
```

But after `int main() {...}`, you **must** declare functions with the `(1)` heading, that way functions know what variables are being sent to them, how are they called and what their type is, so the code will be:

```
double formula(double far, double cel); // or double formula(double, double)
double getDegrees(double far);
void display(double far, double cel);

int main() { /* main block, functions calls etc. */}

double formula(double far, double cel) { /* function declaration */ }
double getDegrees(double far)          { /* function declaration */ }
void display(double far, double cel)   { /* function declaration */ }
```

In order to know whether there are any warnings or/and errors in your code, be sure to compile it with these flags: `-Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Also small tip - `void` functions do not have any "informations" to return, thus you do not have to use `return;` in their body.

Comment: Thanks so much! This site is amazing for those of us just learning.